# Is there any restriction for number of requests in Mapkit and MKDirections?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkdirection

I used Google Maps API **https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json** for drawing route and getting direction, but when its usees increases, we have to pay charges. 
I check in iOS and get that we use mapkit's MKDirections but I have a question that 
Is there any charges for its uses or any limitation?
If there is no limits, is there any the drawbacks of using MapKit? 
Is there any cases when Google Maps API become more helpful?

Comment: I get one link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html and from that I got note that 
There are no request limits per app or developer ID, so well-written apps that operate correctly should experience no problems. However, throttling may occur in a poorly written app that creates an extremely large number of requests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either is a stronger offering by map quality alone. However, google maps requires expensive fees if you gain scale where as "MapKit is free forever" so that's advantage by Apple. Additionally, MK won't require a heavy third party dependency like GMaps (12+ MB compiled), so that's another advantage Apple. Where GMaps shines is street view and for directions in less urban international places, for example MapKit directions and local places/businesses are fine in the US but I wouldn't rely on them in Argentina or New Zealand.

Another advantage of Mapkit is that MapKit has a much better integration with CoreLocation and CoreAnimation. The “Follow user location” mode is missing in Google Maps; as well, the ability to add advanced animations to annotations (MKAnnotation is represented by a UIView, while a GMSMarker is represented by a UIImage) can give your app an appealing touch that the Google Maps SDK just can’t.

As you are going to show address and picture on the marker, so Apple's Map Kit will be better option to work with.

[Show this for more information about Mapkit](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer MapKit over Google Maps because of the better integration in iOS, a more powerful API and the better looking map material. However Google maps is in some (or most?) areas better than Apple Maps when it comes map details and correctness. This might change since Apple is creating new map material at the moment. But it will take some time to create new maps for the whole world.

Apple Maps is free. Its included in the package the customer buys when purchasing an Apple product. There is a request limit. I experienced timeouts when sending about 200 Requests / min (for resolving large amounts of addresses). Your requests will work again after 5 min or something. So exceeding the request limit is not that easy and it won't be "banned" for too long.